# In SSIS ADO NET works OK but OLE DB fails

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis-2012

In SSIS I have a dataflow where I am uploading a CSV file to SQL Server 2012. Everything works fine for me when the destination has the ADO NET connection string, but I need to change the connection string to OLE DB. When I make the change and execute it, I get the following error:

> [OLE DB Destination [241]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

The funny thing is that if I open the CSV file with Excel and delete a random row, I go back and try and with that the change to OLE DB works perfectly for me.

What's going on?

Comment: Why do you "need to change the connection string to OLE DB", when you have a working solution with the ADO.NET connector?

Comment: Can you try changing a value slightly instead?  I'm curious if it's the save by Excel that makes the difference in case it's some odd ASCII or UTF sort of thing.

Comment: The "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" is deprecated already for five years. It is better to start using **Microsoft OLEDB Driver** instead. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2218891

Comment: Thank you all for responding. Run a new test, delete one of the records using Notepad, save it, and run again. The result the same error.
So how could you change the encoding that is similar to what Excel gives you?

Comment: You're right, it's a funny thing that you're using Excel to modify CSV files since it's known to break more files than it fixes due to its mishandling of international characters and UTF8 encoding. Probably your original CSV file has fields that contain comma, linebreak or quote characters and  doesn't follow encoding conventions correctly.

Comment: I did the modification from excel by coincidence.
however when doing the upload of the file if it works ok. But I need the ETL to do the same thing that Excel does to load the file using the OLE DB connection